# Mvvm drag grid in window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I found solution which allows to drag grid in a window. But I am using MVVM.
How it can be done in MVVM? What i need to use?Content control or somethimg else?

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Blue" 
  Width="100" Height="100" 
  MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp">
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="tt"/>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

```
<Window x:Name="window" ...>
<Grid x:Name="grid"...
```

```
Point m_start;
Vector m_startOffset;

private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
m_start = e.GetPosition(window);
m_startOffset = new Vector(tt.X, tt.Y);
grid.CaptureMouse();
}

private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
if (grid.IsMouseCaptured)
{
    Vector offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition(window), m_start);

    tt.X = m_startOffset.X + offset.X;
    tt.Y = m_startOffset.Y + offset.Y;
}
}

private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
grid.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do here with MVVM. if you want to move things and get the events from the mouse/window this can only be done by code behind.
MVVM command/RelayCommand are for the model/viewmodel/View handling. not for mouse,window interaction.

you can use input bindings and more, but basically what you are doing is the correct way to go